# TableLayoutPanel - vertical scrollbar when needed

Tags: c#, scrollbar, autoscroll, tablelayoutpanel

I have created a TableLayoutPanel within a panel. The problem is that when the TableLayoutPanel height exceeds its MaximumSize, the rows overlap one-other. Instead, I expect a vertical scrollbar that allows me to navigate the table. Here they are some properties for the panel, that might affect this problem:

- AutoScroll = False
- AutoSize = False
- MaximumSize = (0,0) (default)
- MinimumSize = (0,0) (default)
- Dock = None

And some properties for the TableLayoutPanel :

- AutoSize = false;
- AutoScroll = true;
- Size = (450, some_value) - some_value is dynamic
- MaximumSize = (450, 200) - I don't want that TableLayoutPanel occupies more than 200px of the panel (parent) height.

If I let MaximumSize to its default value, the table just shows me as many records as it can within 200px (depending on the row height).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure all your row styles are either `Absolute` or `AutoSize`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks man :) !  It should be `AutoSize`, and now it's working . You made my day.